# How do I schedule a stored procedure to run daily at certain time?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-administration, dbms-scheduler

I am trying to schedule a stored procedure in Oracle, it should run daily at a certain time, for example at 11:59 pm

```
 BEGIN
 DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
 job_name           =>  'BLANKET_WO',
 job_type           =>  'STORED_PROCEDURE',
 job_action         =>  'AAKPID.BLANKET_WO_PROC',
 repeat_interval    =>  'FREQ=DAILY;BYHOUR=23;BYMINUTE=59');
 END;
 /
```

Will this code work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it should work:

```
 BEGIN
 DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
 job_name           =>  'BLANKET_WO',
 job_type           =>  'STORED_PROCEDURE',
 job_action         =>  'AAKPID.BLANKET_WO_PROC',
 start_date         =>  '16-nov-2017 11:50:00 pm',
 repeat_interval    =>  'FREQ=DAILY;BYHOUR=23;BYMINUTE=59',
 enabled            =>  true
);
 END;
 /
```

Comment: Will this run on 59 th minute ?

Comment: @AmeyaLokhande yes, you may try for a near future with respect to your local time.

Comment: Note: there's no need to specify `start_date` unless you want to delay it for some reason - the default behaviour is to start as soon as the job is enabled. Also, `start_date` is not a string parameter (it's a `timestamp with time zone`) so relying on implicit conversion from a string is less than ideal.